# How to install VMware Player 12 on 32-bit Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware-player

Today downloaded VMware Player 12 to my Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit laptop. I am trying to install it but get the error **This installation package is not support by this process type  contact product vendor**.

[image]

How can I install the player software?

Answer (score 7):

VMware Player 12 is a 64-bit application.  It cannot be installed on a 32-bit operating system

### What are the minimum PC requirements to install and use VMware Workstation Player?

> For a typical host system, we recommend that you have a 1 GHz or
>   faster 64-bit processor (2GHz recommended) and 2GB RAM minimum (4GB
>   RAM recommended). You must have enough memory to run the 64-bit host
>   operating system, plus the memory required for each guest operating
>   system and for applications on the host and guest. See your guest
>   operating system and application documentation for their memory
>   requirements. VMware Player requires approximately 150MB of disk space
>   to install the application. For more details on minimum PC
>   requirements, see the VMware Player Documentation.

### System Requirements

> - 64-bit x86 Intel Core 2 Duo Processor or equivalent, AMD Athlon™ 64 FX Dual Core Processor or equivalent 1.3GHz or faster core speed
> - 2GB RAM minimum/ 4GB RAM recommended
> - Workstation 12 Player installation:
> - 300MB of available disk space for the application. Additional hard disk space required for each virtual machine. Please refer to vendors
>     recommended disk space for specific guest operating systems.
> - NOTE: Workstation 12 Player requires a 64-bit host operating systemHHost operating systems* (64-bit):
>
>   - Windows 10
>   - Windows 8
>   - Windows 7
>   - Windows Server 2012
>   - Windows Server 2008
>   - Ubuntu 8.04 and above
>   - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 and above
>   - CentOS 5.0 and above
>   - Oracle Linux 5.0 and above
>   - openSUSE 10.2 and above
>   - SUSE Linux 10 and above

### What if I still need to run Workstation 12 Player on a 32-bit Host?

> [`VMWare Player 6`](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0|PLAYER-605|product_downloads) is the last version that supports both a 32-bit and a 64-bit operating systems running on the host PC. However you can
>   purchase Workstation 12 Player and downgrade to Player 6 Plus via the
>   My VMware Portal - please reference knowledge base article "[How to
>   downgrade license keys in My VMware](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2006975)"

[Source](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/faqs/install-requirements.html)

Answer (score 2):

For Workstation, **[VMware Workstation v9](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=293&downloadGroup=WKST-904-WIN)** is the last one that supported 32-bit Windows.

For Player, [**VMware Player v6**](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0%7CPLAYER-607%7Cproduct_downloads) is the last one that supported 32-bit Windows (as others have answered).

Answer (score -1):

Try VMWare Player v6

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0|PLAYER-605|product_downloads

This is the last version to work on 32bit Windows

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.